# Jmeter json path extractor - How to Remove String

Tags: json, path, jmeter, extractor

[image]

I have a problema with the next point:

```
{

    "id":"3be62315-cd79-4e13-9536-0ee496e72184;1.0",
    "objectType":"DOCUMENT",
    "metadata":
    {
        "gdoc:filePath":null,
        "gdoc:filename":"blankOdt.odt",
        "gdoc:machineId":null
    },
    "checkedout":false,
    "immutable":false,
    "latestVersion":false,
    "majorVersion":false,
    "latestMajorVersion":false,
    "contentStreamLength":0
}
```

I need recovery 3be62315-cd79-4e13-9536-0ee496e72184 and not "3be62315-cd79-4e13-9536-0ee496e72184;1.0",

I cant remove ";1.0" of the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

- Suppose your JSON Path PostProcessor  uses variable id for $..id

[image]
- Add a regex post processor after the JSON Post Processor and make it act on the variable

[image]

Then use ${id_part1}

Comment: Thank's very much man!! . It works. =) . I really didn't know that I can use "Regular Expression" with other variables.